# Allow click but disable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link that I needs to be disabled based on some condition. So I have used **CSS** way of disabling it as follows:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none
}

if(some condition) {
  jQuery("#some_link_id").addClass("disabled");
}
```

But, as expected it has disabled all events (like: click, hover, etc). I want to put my own click event on the link if it's disabled, eg:

```
jQuery("#some_link_id.disabled").click(function(){
  alert("Link is disabled");
});
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: use CSS `pointer-events:none;`

Comment: @www139 I have, please read the question

Comment: Sorry (lol -- my bad)

Comment: I wrote my answer, hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use jQuery & no need to use css

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Link is now disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".disabled").click(function() {//all elements with .disabled class
      return false;//disable the link
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.instructables.com">Link text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set pointer events to none, you can't bind any events to the link. It would be better to just dynamically change the output with a function.

```
$('#somelink').click(function(e){
       if( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ){
            // Do this
       } else {
            // Do that
       }
});
```